# I can't join servers on Counter Strike Global Offensive

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I double click a server to join and most of the time a box comes up saying join game, refresh, cancel and the server information so I click refresh then join game but nothing happens and sometimes when I click favourites nothing shows up.

Comment: You can edit your posts using the edit button you see below the tags. I've made the edit for you this time

Comment: Are you doing this from steam? or with the game already launched?

Comment: Is the server full?

Comment: Give more details and screenshots if possible

Comment: Can you note your OS and platform? Also router model if you can determine that.

Answer (score 1):

Is this for both casual and competitive? If so, I suspect you are being blocked by a firewall. Either on your computer or at your router.

The easiest way to determine if this is the cause (before putting in a permeant, correct fix) is to turn off the firewall on your computer (this differs between Mac and Windows). Try the game. If the problem persists, try turning off the firewall on your router (*do not leave this off, turn it back on **right** after testing* regardless of result). Note that some routers may not have this option but how to do it would be in the manual of your router. You'll need admin access too.

Turn both back on.

If turning off either of those allowed you past the problem, you need to identify the ports that CS:GO uses and open them.

Writers Note: I'm aware this this shouldn't be needed (as most firewalls should allow such traffic) however, it's a logical conclusion based on the info we have and worth the OP following up on.

Comment: I can help identify the ports if this proves to be the trouble. You might find the info in the interwebs too.

Answer (score -1):

If that box appears it means you're trying to join servers that are already full.

I would suggest using the filters at the bottom and checking "Hide full servers" to avoid this issue.